# Does NMAP detect SecurityOnion honeypots?

Tags: nmap, honeypot, centos

I'm installing SecurityOnion Intrusion Detection Honeypot. Does NMAP recognise it as CentOS7 or it might give a hint to the hacker that it is a security onion machine build?

Does SecurityOnion have its own fingerprints?

Comment: Sound like it would be easier & faster to test this than ask it on a Q/A site.